# jQuery events for newly created combox from html select

Tags: jquery, events, select, combobox

I need some guidance/advices from someone who has any ideea about custom jquery event.
From a html select I tried to create a "combobox" in which user can type a text and options list would be filtered by that typed text.
That way, html code for an select like

```
<select name="foo_select" id="foo_id">
    <option value="foo_option_value_1">foo_option_text_1</option>
    <option value="foo_option_value_2">foo_option_text_2</option>
    <option value="foo_option_value_3">foo_option_text_3</option>
</select>
```

would be replaced with

```
<div class="combo_container" id="foo_select_container" style="position:relative">
    <input type="text" class="combo_text" />
    <input type="hidden" name="foo_select" id="foo_id" />
    <div class="combo_arrow">
    <ul style="position:absolute;">
        <li id="foo_option_value_1">foo_option_text_1</li>
        <li id="foo_option_value_2">foo_option_text_2</li>
        <li id="foo_option_value_3">foo_option_text_3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So when the user select's a certain "option" from new created "combobox" in the input with class "combo_text" option's text is inserted, and in the hidden input option's id is inserted.

Now, all I need to do is to know when user select's an option. Basically what I need to do is to create the equivalent of jQuery( '#foo_id' ).change( function(){ do_someting } ); for my newly created combobox, but I have no ideea where to start.

If someone has any ideea I would apreciate.

---

Update.

I mention that I have tried to keep as much as I could the behavior of the html select. The combo box has functionalities like: on **up/down** arrows on focused **combo.text** the user can select a value, and on enter that value is changed, calling the function **Select()** or on escape nothing chages - even if user has selected other values using **up/down** arrows.

So I think I need to do something like.. when hidden input **$( '#foo_id' )** is changed *do someting*, so I need to find out when this input's value is changed.

---

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have managed to find a solution and I posted maybe will help someone, and it goes like this:

On hidden input I attached new event called **cmbchange**

```
jQuery( '#foo_id' ).bind( 'cmbchange', function(){
     __do_something__
})
```

And in function Select() I have triggerd that event

```
jQuery( '#foo_id' ).trigger( 'cmbchange' );
```

Pretty simple if you think about it. Great thing that jQuery.
Anyway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this is what you're looking for?

```js
// Should also work on elements that will
// be created later 
$('#foo_select_container li') // Select all <li>s from the container
    .on('click', function (ev) { // 
        // `this` will be bound to the clicked <li> element
        var myId = $(this).attr('id');
        // More code here ...
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. On click it would be ok, but i have tried to keep as much as I could the behavior of the html select, so the selection of an option is made on click on the list item **AND** on enter when input **.combo_text** is focused. When one of this two event si triggerd a function **Select()** is called which sets the input - value, input - text and add's a class "selected" to the list item that was selected.

Answer (score 0):

For ease of manipulation, make sure all the critical elements have a class. If you want multiple instances, ID's will make things more complicated since ID's must be unique, however we will keep the id on the one named input if you need it to manage form logic like validation or whatever

After you create the pseudo select (I assume it is being created with script) will set all code to "find" within the combo_container class so it keeps insulation from other instances

HTML

```
<div class="combo_container" id="foo_select_container" style="position:relative">
    <input type="text" class="combo_text" />
    <input type="hidden" name="foo_select" id="foo_id" class="combo_id"/>
    <div class="combo_arrow">
    <ul style="position:absolute;" class="combo_list"">
        <li id="foo_option_value_1">foo_option_text_1</li>
        <li id="foo_option_value_2">foo_option_text_2</li>
        <li id="foo_option_value_3">foo_option_text_3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var $cont=$('.combo_container')
$cont.find('.combo_list li').click(function(){
        $cont.find('.combo_id').val( this.id);
        $cont.find('.combo_text').val( $(this).text());
})
```

Comment: The ease of manipulation is not a problem; each "combobox" has an object **combo** equivalent, so when I refer to (let's say) $( 'input.combo_text' ) I do it like **combo.text** (for hidden input - **combo.value** or for ul - **combo.list** etc). All those functionalities are already made. My problem is that I need to know when user selects other option using either click on the list (**combo.list**) or enter on focused input (**combo.text**) - I added new info to my question. Thanks